# Changing the class name JS

Tags: javascript

I have this code on the page:

```
<td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--valid" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;"><button type="button" class="CalendarDay__button" aria-label="Choose niedziela, 16 lutego 2020 as your check-in date. It's available." tabindex="-1">16</button></td>
```

I want to change the class name if there is a string "niedziela" in the "aria-label" attribute.
I wrote something, but unfortunately it doesn't work and I don't know what to do. My code:

```
var string = document.getElementsByClassName("CalendarDay CalendarDay--valid").aria-label,
    substring = "niedziela";

if (string.includes(substring)) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("CalendarDay CalendarDay--valid").className = "CalendarDay CalendarDay--blocked CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range";
}
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName return a collection of HTML Element, and you cannot just do .aria-label ... you need to get element by Id and then getAttributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```js
document.querySelector("button[aria-label*=niedziela]").classList.add("CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range");
```

```css
button { background-color:blue }
.CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range { background-color:red }
```

```html
<table><tr>
<td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--valid" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;"><button type="button" class="CalendarDay__button" aria-label="Choose niedziela, 16 lutego 2020 as your check-in date. It's available." tabindex="-1">16</button></td></tr></table>
```

Perhaps just use CSS

Move the CSS under the datepicker one

```css
button[aria-label*=niedziela] { background-color:red }
```

```html
<table><tr>
<td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--valid" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;"><button type="button" class="CalendarDay__button" aria-label="Choose niedziela, 16 lutego 2020 as your check-in date. It's available." tabindex="-1">16</button></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified it a bit (https://jsfiddle.net/krystian_rzepa/fjvkyp0r/2/) and posted it on my wordpress site (https://bagaznikowo.pl), but unfortunately it doesn't work. I mean the search engine on the main page. Do you know why?

Comment: I cannot find anything on your page with niedziela in it except the script. You may want to wrap the code in a load, or you need to wait for the event that puts it on the page. https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/14kLhrwt/

Comment: Those buttons are not available when your script runs. You need to access these buttons from the datepicker script OR CSS and not just in the page.

Comment: Thanks! It works: 
button[aria-label*=niedziela] {
  background-color: white;
  color: #e4e7e7;
  pointer-events: none;
}

Answer (score -1):

Instead of targeting by class of the parent target the button with specified class using 
[document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Then iterate the collection and check if the `aria-label` includes that specific keyword. If so then change the class of the parent using `parentNode`

```js
let buttonDataAttr = document.querySelectorAll('.CalendarDay__button').forEach((item) => {
  let getDataLabel = item.getAttribute('aria-label');
  if (getDataLabel.includes('niedziela')) {
    item.parentNode.className = "CalendarDay CalendarDay--blocked CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range"
  }
})
```

```css
.CalendarDay--blocked {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--valid" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;"><button type="button" class="CalendarDay__button" aria-label="Choose niedziela, 16 lutego 2020 as your check-in date. It's available." tabindex="-1">16</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.CalendarDay__button')
var string = el.getAttribute('aria-label')
var substring = 'niedziela'

if (string.includes(substring)) {
  el.parentNode.className = 'CalendarDay CalendarDay--blocked CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range';
}
```

```html
<td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--valid" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">
  <button type="button" class="CalendarDay__button" aria-label="Choose niedziela, 16 lutego 2020 as your check-in date. It's available." tabindex="-1">16</button>
</td>
```